# Test score equivalence - preparing data for Spearman correlation?

Tags: categorical-data, spearman-rho, scales, binning, psycholinguistics

I have a somewhat theoretical question.

I am trying to establish how closely scores across different language tests (IELTS, TOEFL, C1A, OET, DET) used in public domains match each other, given that they have access to recommended score ranges for each test.

Unfortunately, the different language tests use different scales, e.g. IELTS ranges 0-9 in 0.5 point increments; TOEFL ranges 0-120 in 1-point increments; C1A ranges 142-180 in 1-point increments; OET ranges 0-500 in 10-point increments; DET ranges 10-160 in 5-point increments. As a result, the situation is not a single score for a single score, and more like a single score for a score range. Since I'm using the IELTS scores as the reference point (0-9, 0.5 increments): IELTS 6.5 equals TOEFL 60-78, or C1A 176-179, or OET 300-340, or DET 120-125.

The IELTS score is clearly not a continuous variable, so I was thinking about using a Spearman correlation to see how closely the different scores between tests types match when used in the public domain. Should I bin the TOEFL, C1A, OET, and DET data into the IELTS-equivalent recommended ranges for my SPSS-based analysis?

The theoretical question underneath this is this: Would the Spearman rho of IELTS-TOEFL be more comparable to the standards already set if the data was binned beforehand? And would this affect the correlation value to treat all variables as categorical, i.e. a correlation increase for categorical x categorical (binned) versus a lower correlation for categorical x continuous (unbinned)? I know Spearman works with ranks, but I'm worried that (given the score ranges rather than discrete single scores) that it will affect the results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, even if it means I abandon the Spearman correlation plan.

Comment: I am not familiar with these various language tests, so I am reacting to your question based on impression. My impression is the Spearman's correlation isn't going to tell you "how closely scores across [...] match each other". I would guess that something like Hausdorff's distance is more appropriate.

Comment: This is not a simple problem and there isn't a good simple solution. I am pressed for time right now, but look up test equating to get a sense of the issues.  You may want to hire an expert.

Comment: Are the same people being tested on all of these? Or are they different samples? I'm assuming the latter.

Comment: I'm voting to close because OP has not provided additional information which is relevant to answering this question.